# How to put specific filenames into a specific JSON format using bash or Perl?

Tags: unix, jq

Assuming I'm in the folder like this:

```bash
➜  tmp.lDrLPUOF ls
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 1.zip 2.rb
```

I want to put all the filenames of text files into a specific JSON format like this:

```
{
  "": [
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "1"
    },
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "2"
    },
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I just know how to list all the filenames:

```bash
➜  tmp.lDrLPUOF ls *'.txt'
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

Can I use bash or Perl to achieve this purpose? Thank you very much!

### Edit

Thanks for @Charles Duffy and @Shawn 's great answers. But it's my fault to forget another important piece of information——time. I want to put the filenames into the resulting JSON per their creating time.

The creating time is as below:

```bash
➜  tmp.lDrLPUOF ls -lTr
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 administrator  staff  0 Oct 12 09:35:05 2022 3.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 administrator  staff  0 Oct 12 09:35:08 2022 2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 administrator  staff  0 Oct 12 09:35:12 2022 1.txt
```

So the resulting JSON I wanted should be like this:

```
{
  "": [
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "3"
    },
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "2"
    },
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Only tag for tools your question is _actually about_, not tools you think someone might possibly use in an answer. If your question doesn't include code written in a language, that language probably shouldn't be in the tagging -- think about the `unix` tag for things where you want general UNIX tools to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
{ shopt -s nullglob; set -- *.txt; printf '%s\0' "$@"; } | jq -Rn '
  {"": [ input
         | split("\u0000")[]
         | select(. != "")
         | {"title": "",
            "file": . | rtrimstr(".txt")
           }
       ]
  }
'
```

Let's break this down into pieces.

On the bash side:

- `shopt -s nullglob` tells the shell that if `*.txt` has no arguments, it should emit *nothing at all*, instead of emitting the string `*.txt` as a result.
- `set --` overwrites the argument list in the current context (because this is a block on the left-hand side of the pipeline that context is transient and won't change `"$@"` in code outside the pipe).
- `printf '%s\0' "$@"` prints our arguments, with a NUL character after each one; if there are no arguments at all, it prints only a NUL.

On the jq side:

- `-R` specifies that the input is raw data, not json.
- `-n` specifies that we don't automatically consume any inputs, but will instead use `input` or `inputs` to specify where input should be read.
- `split("\u0000")` splits the input on NULs. (This is important because the NUL is the only character that can't exist in a filename, which is why we used `printf '%s\0'` on the shell end; that way we work correctly with filenames with newlines, literal quotes, whitespace, and all the other weirdness that's able to exist).
- `select(. != "")` ignores empty strings.
- `rtrimstr(".txt")` removes `.txt` from the name.

---

#### Addendum: Sorting by mtime

The jq parts don't need to be modified here: to sort by mtime you can adjust only the shell. On a system with GNU `find`, `sort` and `sed`, this might look like:

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%T@ %P\0' |
  sort -zn |
  sed -z -re 's/^[[:digit:].]+ //g' |
  jq -Rn '
```

...followed by the same jq given above.

Comment: Thanks for your great answers. But it's my fault to forget another important piece of information——time. I want to put the filenames into the resulting JSON per their creating time. I have updated my questions. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't edit questions in a way that invalidates preexisting, correct answers; generally, a missing question element (if caught only after answers already exist) should become a new question. That said -- sorting files by mtime is covered by [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003), and the approach there using `find -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zn` is appropriate for this use case.

Comment: @hustnzj, ...that said, I've added an addendum showing mtime-based sorting.

Comment: Just a tiny correction: `%Tk` is for the last modification time while `%Bk` is for the creating time.

Comment: Another tiny correction to remove the `./` in the result: add the second pattern of sed like this: `'s/^[[:digit:].]+ //g;s/\.\///g'`

Comment: You don't need sed to remove the `./` -- you can just change the format string from `%p` to `%P` so `find` never puts it there in the first place.

Comment: @hustnzj, using modification time was deliberate, because on a majority of Linuxy systems (those using ext3 and ext4, among other common filesystems) creation time isn't tracked. If you're using one of the few filesystems that does support it, by all means, adjust appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If installed, `tree` can be a good alternative to list the contents of directories as it can encode its output as well-defined JSON which comes in handy when dealing with strange file names (and especially when your desired output is JSON anyways).

```bash
tree -JtL 1 -P '*.txt'
```

```json
[
  {"type":"directory","name":".","contents":[
    {"type":"file","name":"3.txt"},
    {"type":"file","name":"2.txt"},
    {"type":"file","name":"1.txt"}
  ]}
,
  {"type":"report","directories":0,"files":3}
]
```

- `tree -J` outputs JSON
- `tree -t` sorts by last modification time
- `tree -L 1` recurses only `1` level deep
- `tree -P '*.txt'` reduces the the list to file pattern `*.txt`

Of course, you can also add more details, if needed, such as

- `tree -p` includes file permissions
- `tree -u` and `tree -g` include user and group names
- `tree -s` includes the file size in bytes
- `tree -D --timefmt '%F %T'` includes the last modification time

```bash
tree -JtL 1 -P '*.txt' -pusD --timefmt='%F %T'
```

```json
[
  {"type":"directory","name":".","mode":"0755","prot":"drwxr-xr-x","user":"hustnzj","size":4096,"time":"2022-10-12 09:35:00","contents":[
    {"type":"file","name":"3.txt","mode":"0644","prot":"-rw-r--r--","user":"hustnzj","size":123,"time":"2022-10-12 09:35:05"},
    {"type":"file","name":"2.txt","mode":"0644","prot":"-rw-r--r--","user":"hustnzj","size":456,"time":"2022-10-12 09:35:08"},
    {"type":"file","name":"1.txt","mode":"0644","prot":"-rw-r--r--","user":"hustnzj","size":789,"time":"2022-10-12 09:35:12"}
  ]}
,
  {"type":"report","directories":0,"files":3}
]
```

> A note regarding [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74035356/how-to-put-specific-filenames-into-a-specific-json-format-using-bash-or-perl#comment130723331_74035378): `tree -t` sorts by last modification time. There's also an option `tree -c` to sort by (and with `tree -D` to show time as) last status change instead, but there's no dedicated option (I know of) that uses creation/birth times (if supported by the file system).

Then, using that JSON output as input, you can employ `jq` for further filtering and formatting:

```bash
tree … | jq --arg ext '.txt' '
  {"": (first.contents | map(
    select(.type == "file") | {title: "", file: .name | rtrimstr($ext)}
  ))}
'
```

```json
{
  "": [
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "3"
    },
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "2"
    },
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BKYGHqnMtxb)

Note: This includes the filter `select(.type == "file")` as `tree` would also include the names of subdirectories. Drop it if you want them included.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, workable solution, and convenient Demo. I just choose `-c` instead of `-t`. Sorting by the last status change time also has the same effect as the creating time in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Using just `jq`, any shell:

```bash
$ jq  -n --args '{"": [ $ARGS.positional[] | rtrimstr(".txt") | { title: "", file: . } ] }' *.txt 
{
  "": [
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "1"
    },
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "2"
    },
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

The filenames passed on the command line (The expansion of `*.txt` are in the jq variable `$ARGS.positional`. For each one, remove the .txt extension and use the rest in a object of the desired structure.

Or with a perl one-liner:

```bash
$ perl -MJSON::PP -E 'say encode_json({"" => [ map { { title => "", file => s/\.txt$//r } } @ARGV ] })' *.txt
{"":[{"file":"1","title":""},{"title":"","file":"2"},{"file":"3","title":""}]}
```

Comment: One concern here: What if there _are_ no text files? Unless the non-default `nullglob` flag is set, you'll get `*.txt` as an argument, so this would emit an entry for `"file": "*"`. (For compatibility with non-bash shells, one typically uses something like `test -e "$1" || test -L "$1"` to see if the thing `*.txt` evaluated to exists -- that way you can distinguish between evaluating to `*.txt` because the glob had no matches, and evaluating to `*.txt` because that's an actual filename that really exists in your current working directory).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not worried about that. If there's no text files in the directory, just don't run the command.

Comment: Works if it's only ever run by a human who's paying attention, but otherwise you're just pushing correctness work into a different script's scope.

Comment: Your `jq` solution is brilliant. Could you consider sorting the result by the status change time of the files?

Comment: @hustnzj You typically can't access file creation time like you mention in your edit to the question. For inode change time (What I assume you mean by status change), use zsh instead of bash and then `jq ... *.txt(Oc)` for a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

My take:

```bash
stat -c '%Y:%n' *.txt \
| sort -t: -n \
| cut -d: -f2- \
| xargs basename -s .txt \
| jq -s 'map({title: "", file: tostring}) | {"": .}'
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. But if the filename contains a letter, not a pure number, this answer will report an error like this: `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0`.