# How to update a json file by the contents read from other files using jq?

Tags: json, unix, jq

I have several text files, each one has a **title** inside. For example:

```bash
echo 'title: hello' > 1.txt
echo 'title: world' > 2.txt
echo 'title: good' > 3.txt
```

And I have a JSON file called *abc.json* generated by a shell script like this:

```json
{
  "": [
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "1"
    },
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "2"
    },
    {
      "title": "",
      "file": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want is to update the **title** value in the *abc.json* by the **title** in the respective text file, like this:

```json
{
  "": [
    {
      "title": "hello",
      "file": "1"
    },
    {
      "title": "world",
      "file": "2"
    },
    {
      "title": "good",
      "file": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

The text files and the JSON files are in the same directory like this:

```bash
➜  tmp.uFtH6hMC ls
1.txt    2.txt    3.txt    abc.json
```

Thank you very much!

### Update requirement

Sorry, guys. All your answers are perfect for the above requirement.

But some important detailed information I missed:

1. The filename of text files may contain space, so the current directory should be like this:

   ```bash
   ➜  $ gfind . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%P\n'
   The text file contain one title line and more content.txt
   The title identifier in the text file is fixed.txt
   The filename of text file may contain space.txt
   abc.json
   ```
2. The text files include one **title-line** which contains the **title-value** that will be extracted into the *abc.json*, i.e., `## hello` means that "hello" need to be put into `title` field in *abc.json*. The **title-line**, could be anyline in the file, looks like `## <title-value>`. The **title-identifier** `##` is fixed and sperated with **title-value** by one single whitespace which is the first whitespace in the **title-line**. So the text files content could look like this:

   *The text file contain one title line and more content.txt*:

   ```
   ## hello world
   some more content below...
   ...
   ```

   *The title identifier in the text file is fixed.txt*:

   ```
   ## How are you?
   some more content below...
   ...
   ```

   *The filename of text file may contain space.txt*:

   ```
   some pre-content...
   ...

   ## I'm fine, thank you.

   some more content below...
   ...
   ```
3. Before updating, the *abc.json* looks like this:

   ```bash
   {
     "": [
       {
         "title": "",
         "file": "The filename of text file may contain space"
       },
       {
         "title": "",
         "file": "The text file contain one title line and more content"
       },
       {
         "title": "",
         "file": "The title identifier in the text file is fixed"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
4. After updating, the *abc.json* should be like this:

   ```json
   {
     "": [
       {
         "title": "I'm fine, thank you.",
         "file": "The filename of text file may contain space"
       },
       {
         "title": "hello world",
         "file": "The text file contain one title line and more content"
       },
       {
         "title": "How are you?",
         "file": "The title identifier in the text file is fixed"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   Sorry again...thank you for your patience and great help!

Comment: Would be a lot easier if the n.txt files were json

Comment: This is basically your previous question - [How to put specific filenames into a specific JSON format using bash or Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74035356/5291015) with an additional requirement now

Comment: What did you try on your own?

Comment: How is your `title` composed? Is it always one word or multiple words with spaces or newlines? You need to atleast explain the requirements a bit more detailed to get an answer that handles all the corner cases

Comment: @Inian Sorry to miss some detailed information. Next time I will try to consider it more comprehensive. Thanks for your kindly reminding.

Comment: @hustnzj now all answers are basically useless, because your question is completely different. Please open a new question if you have a different question. StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum where people build solutions iteratively. You post a question, you get answers, you accept the best answer. If you have a new/different question, post a new question (potentially linking the old question or incorporating parts of the solution/answers).

Comment: @hustnzj your requirements are already quite complicated, but I'm afraid that posting more answers is not the end of it. The file format has changed considerably already. Now, what happens if a file contains multiple "titles"? Is that possible? I wouldn't wonder if it is, given that titles can even be in the middle of the file!

Comment: And why was the original version of this question "I have files with 'title: the title' in them", when the files very clearly don't have "title": in them, but a different prefix as communicated in the updated requirements. Why wasn't this part of the original question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shell loop to iterate over your files, extract the second column, create each array element and then transform the stream of array elements into your final object:

```
for f in *.txt; do
  cut -d' ' -f2- "$f" | jq -R --arg file "$f" '{title:.,file:($file/"."|first)}';
done | jq -s '{"":.}'
```

It is also possible to remove the file extension in shell directly, which makes the jq filter a little bit simpler:

```
for f in *.txt; do
  cut -d' ' -f2- "$f" | jq -R --arg file "${f%.txt}" '{title:.,$file}';
done | jq -s '{"":.}'
```

`cut` extracts the title value and must be adapted if the files are structured differently, e.g. by using grep, sed, or awk to extract the title and then feed it to jq.

Comment: @Inian fair enough, in that case `cut -f2-` :) edited, thanks!

Comment: After the question has taken a 180° turn: I won't change the answer, because that's not how StackOverflow works. Instead, I will leave a comment what needs to be adapted: change `cut` to `grep | cut` or use `sed` to extract the title. The rest of this answer should still work, even with the new/current requirements. Multiple titles in a single file won't be handled.

Comment: Sorry to change the requirement so drastically. Thanks for telling me how StackOverflow works. Next time I will post a new question in a similar situation. I accept your answer. I really appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `.title` and `.files` has the same number, we can use that to index it from the input.

So using `cut` we can read all the `*.txt` files, split on   and then get the second to last field, this gives:

```
cat *.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1-
hello
world
good
```

(titles with spaces will work due to the `-f 1-`)

---

Using `--arg` we pass that to jq, which we then parse into an array:

```
($inputs | split("\n")) as $parsed
```

Now that `$parsed` looks like:

```json
[
  "hello",
  "world",
  "good"
]
```

---

To update the value, loop over each object in the `""` array, then get the matching value from `$parsed` by using `.file | tonumber - 1` (since array are 0-indexed)

```
jq --arg inputs "$(cat *.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1-)" \
    '($inputs | split("\n")) as $parsed
        | .""[]
        |= (.title = $parsed[.file | tonumber - 1])' \
abc.json
```

Output:

```json
{
  "": [
    {
      "title": "hello",
      "file": "1"
    },
    {
      "title": "world",
      "file": "2"
    },
    {
      "title": "good",
      "file": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Valid points, thanks @Inian. Changed the `sed` to allow spaces. Tested.

Answer (score 0):

Use `input_filename` to get the input files' names, read their raw content with the `-R` flag set, and use `select` to find the right item to update; all in one go:

```bash
jq -Rn --argfile base abc.json '
  reduce (inputs | [
    ltrimstr("title: "),
    (input_filename | rtrimstr(".txt"))
  ]) as [$title, $file] ($base;
    (.[""][] | select(.file == $file)).title = $title
  )
' *.txt
```

If the left part of the text files' contents ("title" in the samples) should be a dynamic field name, you could `capture` it as well:

```bash
jq -Rn --argfile base abc.json '
  reduce (inputs | [
    capture("^(?<key>.*): (?<value>.*)$"),
    (input_filename | rtrimstr(".txt"))
  ]) as [{$key, $value}, $file] ($base;
    (.[""][] | select(.file == $file))[$key] = $value
  )
' *.txt
```

Output:

```json
{
  "": [
    {
      "title": "hello",
      "file": "1"
    },
    {
      "title": "world",
      "file": "2"
    },
    {
      "title": "good",
      "file": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```